# How do I decide which manpage to use on the Ubuntu Manuals site?

Tags: manpage

I've found the Ubuntu Manuals site (http://manpages.ubuntu.com) very useful for looking up manpages when I'm not at a computer with Ubuntu on it. However, I've found that sometimes the search results table links to multiple manpages with the same name.

For example, performing [this search for `grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=grep) results in two links for each distribution, both labeled `grep(1)`: one to [`grep.1posix.html`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/grep.1posix.html) and one to [`grep.1.html`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/grep.1.html).

I've heard of Ubuntu being "POSIX-compliant", so how do I know which manpage will be most applicable to a typical Ubuntu install? (Or, how do I know which manpage shows up when I use the `man` command?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `man` manual page says:

```
A section, if provided, will direct man to look only in that section of the manual.
The default action is to search in all of the available sections, following a 
pre-defined order and to show only the first  page  found,  even  if
page exists in several sections.
```

In the config file `/etc/manpath.config` you find the actual order used:

```
1 n l 8 3 2 3posix 3pm 3perl 5 4 9 6 7
```

Also, `man -a $command` will show all pages found in all sections, and `-S $section-list` option override default order.

A last note: you probably will find `man 1posix grep` will not work on your system, because the package `manpages-posix` is not installed by default.